# Combine rows which have same value in two columns R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like:

```
       A      B    C     
1.     80     1    12    
2.     80     1    13    
3.     80     2    14    
4.     81     2    15    
5 .    81     2    16
```

I want this:

```
       A'     B'    C'     
1.     80     1    12 13   
2.     80     2    14    
3.     81     2    15 16
```

Any suggestion package etc. ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using `aggregate` to group the C values by A and B, here using `paste` (string concatenation) as the aggregating function:

```
> df<-data.frame(A=c(80,80,80,81,81),B=c(1,1,2,2,2),C=12:16)
> 
> df
   A B  C
1 80 1 12
2 80 1 13
3 80 2 14
4 81 2 15
5 81 2 16
> 
> aggregate(data=df,C~B+A,FUN=paste)
  B  A      C
1 1 80 12, 13
2 2 80     14
3 2 81 15, 16
```

Comment: thanks for your replay

If I had another column, is this possible?


aggregate(data=df,C~B+A, D~B+A, FUN=paste)

Comment: I think you can do that with `aggregate(data=df,cbind(C,D)~B+A,FUN=sum)`