# Create a sequence of strings

Tags: r

Given a data set similar to the following

```
dat = structure(list(OpportunityId = c("006a000000zLXtZAAW", "006a000000zLXtZAAW", 
                                 "006a000000gst", "006a000000gstg", "006a000000gstg", 
                                 "006a000000zLXtZAAW"), IsWon = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
                     sequence = c("LLLML", "LHHHL", "LLLML", "HMLLL", "LLLLL", "LLLLL")), 
                .Names = c("OpportunityId","IsWon", "sequence"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

dat
```

How would one go about adding each sequence that is associated with a particular opportunity id, such that the final looks like.

```
oppid    sequence 
006...   LLL, LML, MMM  
007...   MMM, MML, MMH, LLL, HHH
007...   LML, MMM
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any rules/logic to create the sequence as it is not clear from the input 'dat'.

Comment: This is 100% salesforce data, isn't it? lolol

Comment: I answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38125125/1514952  – you can save a step on the answers below by using `aggregate` with `paste` directly as the aggregating function (sorry, I don't know enough to know how/if I should be marking as duplicate or anything)

Answer (score 2):

We can `paste` the 'sequence' after grouping by 'OpportunityId'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, .(sequence = toString(unique(sequence))) ,
               by = .(oppid = OpportunityId)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a combination of `aggregate` and `unique` could help.

```
aggregate(sequence ~ OpportunityId, dat, unique)
#       OpportunityId            sequence
#1      006a000000gst               LLLML
#2     006a000000gstg        HMLLL, LLLLL
#3 006a000000zLXtZAAW LLLML, LHHHL, LLLLL
```

As pointed out by @akrun in a comment, the sequence column is stored as a list in this case.

If necessary, the list in the `sequence` column can be converted into character format (a single string for each row) by means of:

```
dat$sequence <- sapply(dat$sequence, paste, collapse=", ")
```

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
dat_new <- dat %>% 
    group_by(OpportunityId) %>% 
    summarise(sequence = toString(sequence)) %>% 
    distinct(.keep_all = TRUE)
```

Output

```
#        OpportunityId IsWon            sequence
# 1 006a000000zLXtZAAW     1 LLLML, LHHHL, LLLLL
# 2      006a000000gst     1               LLLML
# 3     006a000000gstg     1        HMLLL, LLLLL
```