# How can I merge row with similar value in column, to get unique value in another column in R

Tags: r, merge, row, unique

Hei,

I would like to merge rows under conditions, when the column NameSize has the same value (example: Chaetoceros), I would like to get the combined value of the columns: August 2018 and August 2019 into respective column by keeping unique value only.

I have this case for many others species in the column NameSize (several more Chaetoceros and others).

Example of part of my data set

[image: Example of part of my data set]

Results expected

[image: Results wanted]

Example of part of my data with dput():

```
structure(list(class = c("Bacillariophyceae", "Bacillariophyceae", 
"Bacillariophyceae", "Bacillariophyceae", "Bacillariophyceae", 
"Bacillariophyceae"), NameSize = c("Attheya longicornis", "Bacterosira bathyomphala", 
"Chaetoceros", "Chaetoceros", "Chaetoceros cf. atlanticus", "Chaetoceros cf. borealis"
), `August 2018` = c("SICE3", "P1,SICE3", "P1,PICE1,SICE3", "PICE1", 
"SICE3", "P1,PICE1,SICE3"), `August 2019` = c("P6,P7,Sice4", 
"P6", "", "P2", "", "")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

results wanted:

```
structure(list(class = c("Bacillariophyceae", "Bacillariophyceae", 
"Bacillariophyceae", "Bacillariophyceae", "Bacillariophyceae"
), NameSize = c("Attheya longicornis", "Bacterosira bathyomphala", 
"Chaetoceros", "Chaetoceros cf. atlanticus", "Chaetoceros cf. borealis"
), `Aug-18` = c("SICE3", "P1,SICE3", "P1,PICE1,SICE3", "SICE3", 
"P1,PICE1,SICE3"), `Aug-19` = c("P6,P7,Sice4", "P6", "P2", NA, 
NA)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(class = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), NameSize = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), `Aug-18` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), `Aug-19` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

Comment: Does anyone know why the [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38125125/combine-rows-which-have-same-value-in-two-columns-r) does not work for this post?

Comment: @Jeremy, Yes, because here datewise items are collected as a single string.  These have to be first parsed into individual items then again collected into string after concatenation and checking for unique. The example linked in simple collection of different items into one string

Answer (score 0):

```
p <- structure(list(class = c("Bacillariophyceae", "Bacillariophyceae", 
                              "Bacillariophyceae", "Bacillariophyceae", "Bacillariophyceae", 
                              "Bacillariophyceae"), NameSize = c("Attheya longicornis", "Bacterosira bathyomphala", 
                                                                 "Chaetoceros", "Chaetoceros", "Chaetoceros cf. atlanticus", "Chaetoceros cf. borealis"
                              ), `August 2018` = c("SICE3", "P1,SICE3", "P1,PICE1,SICE3", "PICE1", 
                                                   "SICE3", "P1,PICE1,SICE3"), `August 2019` = c("P6,P7,Sice4",
```

I did this using the librar "pdlyr"

```
p1 <- p %>% group_by(class, NameSize) %>%
  summarise(`August 2018` = first(`August 2018`),
            `August 2019` = last(`August 2019`)) %>% 
  as.data.frame()
```

Hope this works for you

```
  class             NameSize                   `August 2018`  `August 2019`
  <chr>             <chr>                      <chr>          <chr>        
1 Bacillariophyceae Attheya longicornis        SICE3          "P6,P7,Sice4"
2 Bacillariophyceae Bacterosira bathyomphala   P1,SICE3       "P6"         
3 Bacillariophyceae Chaetoceros                P1,PICE1,SICE3 "P2"         
4 Bacillariophyceae Chaetoceros cf. atlanticus SICE3          ""           
5 Bacillariophyceae Chaetoceros cf. borealis   P1,PICE1,SICE3 ""
```

Comment: This is not going to work in other complicated cases.  Simply `first` & `last` won't combine two (or more) different lists and take out unique values from those!!

Answer (score 0):

Since, your data contains a lot of white spaces/"" instead of NAs, you'll have to take two extra steps.  Nevertheless, this will work

```r
df <- structure(list(class = c("Bacillariophyceae", "Bacillariophyceae", 
                               "Bacillariophyceae", "Bacillariophyceae", "Bacillariophyceae", 
                               "Bacillariophyceae"), NameSize = c("Attheya longicornis", "Bacterosira bathyomphala", 
                                                                  "Chaetoceros", "Chaetoceros", "Chaetoceros cf. atlanticus", "Chaetoceros cf. borealis"
                               ), `August 2018` = c("SICE3", "P1,SICE3", "P1,PICE1,SICE3", "PICE1", 
                                                    "SICE3", "P1,PICE1,SICE3"), `August 2019` = c("P6,P7,Sice4", 
                                                                                                  "P6", "", "P2", "", "")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                              "tbl", "data.frame"))
library(tidyverse)
df %>% group_by(class, NameSize) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ifelse(. == '', NA, .))) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), ~list(str_split(., ','))), .groups = 'keep') %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~map_chr(., ~unlist(.x) %>% unique() %>% 
                                         na.omit %>% toString))) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ifelse(. == '', NA, .))) %>%
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>   class             NameSize                   `August 2018`    `August 2019`
#>   <chr>             <chr>                      <chr>            <chr>        
#> 1 Bacillariophyceae Attheya longicornis        SICE3            P6, P7, Sice4
#> 2 Bacillariophyceae Bacterosira bathyomphala   P1, SICE3        P6           
#> 3 Bacillariophyceae Chaetoceros                P1, PICE1, SICE3 P2           
#> 4 Bacillariophyceae Chaetoceros cf. atlanticus SICE3            <NA>         
#> 5 Bacillariophyceae Chaetoceros cf. borealis   P1, PICE1, SICE3 <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Glad that it helped. Please accept the answer as per usual practice on SO.